# How this print statement works?

Tags: java

```
interface TestA {
    String toString();
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(new TestA() {
            public String toString() {
                return "test";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This will print ***`test`*** as output.

1. Can anyone explain how this works?
2. When I change the method name `toString()` as `printString`, it will print
   only a memory address.Explain how it works.

Comment: `TestA` is an object, which has override the `toString` method (from `Object`), which is used by `PrintStream` (`PrintStream` calls the object's `toString` method).  The default implementation of `toString` prints the objects `hashcode`

Answer (score 3):

The code:

```
new TestA() {
    public String toString() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

is an anonymous class, which can be thought of as a sort of on-the-fly class definition and instantiation.  This class definition implements a `toString()` method, which happens to return the string `test`.  This anonymous class, when passed to `System.out.println`, then would result in `test` being printed.

If you change `TestA#toString` to `TestA#printString`, then there is no longer an implementation of `toString`, and the default behavior of Java is to print the hashcode.

Answer (score 2):

The `Object` class defines a method `toString()` that returns a "String representation" of the object. The base method returns the class name and hash code.

It's generally a good idea to *override* the `toString()` method and return a better representation.

There are many things in Java that will call an object's `toString()` method. `System.out.println()` is one of them. Another common one is the `+` operator when you are concatenating to a String (like `"hello " + myObj`).

In your first example, you're creating an *anonymous inner class* instance of the `TestA` interface, and overriding `toString()`. That means that `System.out.println()` prints the `"test"` String you defined.

If you rename the method, now you just get the default `Object` implementation of `toString()`, and get the "memory address" version.

Answer (score 1):

`Object` is the super class of all the classes in Java and it has a method `toString()` which prints the object reference.
If you print any object, java compiler internally invokes the `toString()` method on the object.
Here you are printing `new TestA()` so it is calling `toString` method internally, which you have overridden to print `test`.

But when you change the name of the method then it calls the `toString` implementation of `Object` class.